# How can I loop over all game objects in hierarchy including disabled objects all children too in both scenes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class CompareObjects : EditorWindow
{
    string searchString = "";
    List<GameObject> items = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject)).ToList();

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal(EditorStyles.toolbar);
        GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
        searchString = GUILayout.TextField(searchString, EditorStyles.toolbarTextField);
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        // Do comparison here. For example
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            if (items[i].name.Contains(searchString))
            {
                GUI.Label(items[i].name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first problem is I can't convert the array of :

```
FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject))
```

To List.

Seconds how can I loop over the objects in two scenes ? I want to make a comparison between scene a and scene b objects and to be able also to narrow the searching for objects with specific component/s and list the results in the EditorWindow : List A the objects with components in scene A and List B the objects with components in scene B

For example if I type in the search bar : Space,BoxCollider
Then it should find all objects in both scenes that contain the name Space and that also have a BoxCollider attached or without a BoxCollider attached.

I want to know in the result what objects name Space have boxcollider and what not.

Example :

```
List A : Space1 BoxCollider -- Scene A
List A : Space2 Empty -- Scene A

List B : Space1 Empty -- Scene B
List B : Space2 BoxCollider -- Scene B
```

Something like this comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't convert the array of

Method `FindObjectsOfType(Type)` return array of objects, to cast those objects to list you can use LINQ method [OfType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.8):

```
List<GameObject> items = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject)).OfType<GameObject>.ToList();
```

Or just use generic override of method `FindObjectsOfType<T>()`

```
List<GameObject> items = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>().ToList();
```

> Seconds how can I loop over the objects in two scenes ?

You need select all scenes from `SceneManager` and make loop over it's `GetRootGameObjects()`.

If you need to loop all objects and make some manual calculations - you can loom manually like was [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58262442/how-can-i-sort-the-loop-to-debug-log-the-gameobjects-according-to-the-scenes-ord/58267381#58267381). If you know what exactly components you need you can use method `public Component[] GetComponentsInChildren(Type t, bool includeInactive);` with scene root objects (make sure then you set  `includeInactive` to `True` if you want to search in inactive objects)

> I want to know in the result what objects name Space have boxcollider and what not.

```
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public static class Searcher
{
    [MenuItem("Tools/PrintSearch")]
    public static void PrintSearch()
    {
        var objectName = "Space";
        var componentType = typeof(BoxCollider);

        var scenes = Enumerable.Range(0, SceneManager.sceneCount)
            .Select(SceneManager.GetSceneAt)
            .ToArray();
        var objectsWithNames = scenes
            .ToDictionary(s => s, s=> GetSceneObjectsWithName(s, objectName.ToLower()));

        var forLog = objectsWithNames
            .SelectMany(pair => pair.Value.Select(child =>
                $"Scene {pair.Key.name}: object name '{child.gameObject.name}' {(child.GetComponent(componentType) != null ? "contains" : "do not contains")} component {componentType.Name}"));

        Debug.Log(string.Join("\n", forLog));
    }

    private static Transform[] GetSceneObjectsWithName(Scene scene, string objectName)
    {
        return scene.GetRootGameObjects()
            .SelectMany(g => GetChildHierarchyRecursively(g.transform))
            .Where(t=>t.gameObject.name.ToLower().Contains(objectName))
            .ToArray();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Transform> GetChildHierarchyRecursively(Transform parentTransform)
    {
        yield return parentTransform;
        if (parentTransform.childCount > 0)
            yield return parentTransform;
    }
}
```