# How can I sort the loop to debug.log the gameobjects according to the scenes order in the hierarchy?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class CompareObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject[] allObjects;

    private void Start()
    {
        allObjects = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();

        foreach (GameObject go in allObjects)
        {
            Debug.Log(go.name + " >>>>> " + go.scene.name + " >>>>> is active object");
        }
    }
}
```

Now it's starting with objects from the second scene I added for testing then loop over the objects sometimes in the middle of the first scene then back to the second.

Instead I want that it always will loop the top scene objects in the hierarchy and the next scene to the bottom.

If the hierarchy is like this :

```
Scene 1
  GameObject t1
Scene 2
  GameObject t2
Scene 3
  GameObject t1
```

Then first loop t1 of Scene 1 then t2 and t1 of scene 3

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public static class EditorHelpers
{
    [MenuItem("Tools/PrintHierarchy")]
    public static void PrintHierarchy()
    {
        var scenes = Enumerable.Range(0, SceneManager.sceneCount)
            .Select(SceneManager.GetSceneAt)
            .Select(s => $"Scene {s.name}\n{GetSceneHierarchy(s.GetRootGameObjects())}")
            .ToArray();
        Debug.Log(string.Join("\n", scenes));
    }

    private static string GetSceneHierarchy(GameObject[] gameObjects)
    {
        var child = gameObjects.Select(g => GetChildHierarchyRecursively(g.transform)).ToArray();
        return string.Join("\n", child);
    }

    private static string GetChildHierarchyRecursively(Transform parentTransform, string indent = " ")
    {
        var res = indent + parentTransform.name + "\n"
                  + string.Join("\n",
                      Enumerable.Range(0, parentTransform.childCount)
                          .Select(i => GetChildHierarchyRecursively(parentTransform.GetChild(i), indent += " ")));
        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order the array using Linq's `OrderBy` query.

You can then sort them by the scene index in your build settings, or the scene name, or whatever field/property available for the Scene class.

```
using System.Linq;

foreach (GameObject go in allObjects.OrderBy(x => x.scene.buildIndex)
{
    Debug.Log(go.name + " >>>>> " + go.scene.name + " >>>>> is active object");
}
```

Alternatively you can group them by scene

```
foreach (var scene_objects in allObjects.GroupBy(x => x.scene))
{
    Debug.Log("Scene: " + scene_objects.Key.name);

    foreach (GameObject go in scene_objects)
    {
        Debug.Log(go.name + " >>>>> " + go.scene.name + " >>>>> is active object");
    }
}
```